# Solving a linear algebra problem of the form "For what $x$ below vectors are linearly independent?"

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

Let $v_1,v_2, v_3, v_4$ be four vectors, parametrized by $e$. How can I solve the following type of the problem in Mathematica?

> For what values of $e$ four vectors $v_i$ are linearly independent?

The followings are an example of four vectors. vecs[[i]] is the $i$-th vector.

```
$Assumptions = { \[CapitalDelta] > 0, 0 < \[Phi] < 2 Pi, e > 0};
vecs = {{(
   E^(I \[Phi]) (-I e + 
      Sqrt[-e^2 + \[CapitalDelta]^2]))/\[CapitalDelta], (
   I E^(I \[Phi]) (-I e + 
      Sqrt[-e^2 + \[CapitalDelta]^2]))/\[CapitalDelta], -I, 1}, {(
   E^(I \[Phi]) (I e + 
      Sqrt[-e^2 + \[CapitalDelta]^2]))/\[CapitalDelta], -((
    I E^(I \[Phi]) (I e + 
       Sqrt[-e^2 + \[CapitalDelta]^2]))/\[CapitalDelta]), I, 
   1}, {-((E^(
     I \[Phi]) (I e + 
       Sqrt[-e^2 + \[CapitalDelta]^2]))/\[CapitalDelta]), -((
    I E^(I \[Phi]) (I e + 
       Sqrt[-e^2 + \[CapitalDelta]^2]))/\[CapitalDelta]), -I, 
   1}, {-((E^(
     I \[Phi]) (-I e + 
       Sqrt[-e^2 + \[CapitalDelta]^2]))/\[CapitalDelta]), (
   I E^(I \[Phi]) (-I e + 
      Sqrt[-e^2 + \[CapitalDelta]^2]))/\[CapitalDelta], I, 1}}
```

I suspect the answer is $e= \Delta |\cos (\phi/2)|$.

Comment: It is the complement to the set where the determinant is zero. That in turn can be found like so `In[206]:= Solve[{Det[vecs] == 0, \[CapitalDelta] > 0, 
  0 < \[Phi] < 2 Pi, e > 0}, e]

Out[206]= {{e -> 
   ConditionalExpression[\[CapitalDelta], \[CapitalDelta] > 0 && 
     0 < \[Phi] < 2 \[Pi]]}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way which exploits only the definition of the linear independence of vectors is as follows.

```
Resolve[ForAll[{c1, c2, c3, c4}, Implies[c1*vecs[[1]] + c2*vecs[[2]] + c3*vecs[[3]] + 
 c4*vecs[[4]] == {0, 0, 0, 0},   c1 == 0 && c2 == 0 && c3 == 0 && c4 == 0]]]
```

> $\Delta  e^{i \phi } \sqrt{\Delta ^2-e^2}\neq 0$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! All answers here are great but I think this is the most direct and easily generalizable one.

Answer (score 2):

The determinant of the scalarproduct matrix of vecs must not vanish:

```
det = Outer[Dot, vecs, vecs, 1] // Det // Simplify
(*(256 E^(4 I \[Phi]) (e^2 - \[CapitalDelta]^2)^2)/\[CapitalDelta]^4*)
```

The four vectors are indipendent if `E^2 != \[CapitalDelta]^2`

Answer (score 2):

another option is to use `Reduce` and look for solution which has all `a1,a2,a3,a4` as zeros.

```
c = {a1, a2, a3, a4};
eqs = Thread[vecs . c == {0, 0, 0, 0}];
Reduce[eqs, {a1, a2, a3, a4}]
```

Looking at output shows one condition where all are zero. THis is the one you want

[image]

Therefore

[image]

This final step could be automated to pick this condition, but for now, just looking at it is enough :)